# Case statement to for a table with and or conditions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012, case

I have a table name

```
Spend:

id   value  type  date          total
1    21       ar   3/3/2012       45
2    24       az   3/3/2012       55
3    25       az   3/3/2012       55
4    25       az   3/3/2012       45
5    25       ar   3/3/2012       45
```

Condition: 
APR=(value=25 and type like 'ar') or(total=55)

How can i write case statement in select statement with out using #temp and cte's in single select statement.

The output of select statement must be

```
id   value  type  date          total  APR
1    21       ar   3/3/2012       45    0
2    24       az   3/3/2012       55    1
3    25       az   3/3/2012       55    1
4    25       az   3/3/2012       45    0
5    25       ar   3/3/2012       45    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT IIF((Value = 25 and  type like 'ar') or (total=55)', 1, 0) AS APR, *
FROM   Spend
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT id,value,type,date,total,APR,
       CASE WHEN (value=25 and type like 'ar') OR (total=55) Then 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Apr]
FROM Table1
```

[**CASE**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)